# hbase.HServerAddress: Could not resolve the DNS name of slave1 : hostname can't be null

Tags: hadoop, tomcat7, hbase, java-7, apache-zookeeper

Do anyone know why this error appears?... The code was working before but now it is not working in my system but works in other systems successfully. The error log is as below... Please help me...

I think there may have any version incompatibilities... But I don't know what exactly is?...

```
 12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.1-942149, built on 05/07/2010 17:14 GMT
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:host.name=User-PC
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.version=1.7.0
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.class.path=D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;.
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\temp
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Windows 7
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=x86
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=6.1
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=User
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=C:\Users\User
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\bin
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=192.168.1.240:2222 sessionTimeout=180000 watcher=hconnection
    12/10/18 14:21:59 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server /192.168.1.240:2222
    12/10/18 14:22:00 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to JAI-3/192.168.1.240:2222, initiating session
    12/10/18 14:22:00 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server JAI-3/192.168.1.240:2222, sessionid = 0x13a6d1375aa0244, negotiated timeout = 40000
    12/10/18 14:22:02 ERROR hbase.HServerAddress: Could not resolve the DNS name of slave1
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: hostname can't be null
    Error while establishing connection to HBASE
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HServerAddress.getResolvedAddress(HServerAddress.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HServerAddress.<init>(HServerAddress.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterAddressTracker.getMasterAddress(MasterAddressTracker.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getMaster(HConnectionManager.java:354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.<init>(HBaseAdmin.java:94)
        at com.wlu.orm.hbase.connection.HBaseConnection.<init>(HBaseConnection.java:28)
        at com.project.common.HBaseConnectionWrapper.<init>(HBaseConnectionWrapper.java:31)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:110)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:280)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: it seem that you have a problem with your host file, can you post the content of /etc/hosts ?

Comment: How did you end up solving this?